# Match column_name to Column data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to work with a two (already) generated tables.
In one table 1 there is a column named `column_code`
In table 2 the columns are named like the data in `column_code`

Per example
Table 1:

```
meta_data
----------------------------------
| pid         | 1                |
| question    | favorite website |
| column_code | AA123ZZ          |
----------------------------------
```

where `column_code` has a content named: `'AA123ZZ'`
and question is called: what is your favorite website

Table 2:

```
content
-----------------------------------
| id          | 4                 |
| submit_date | 14-01-2013        |
| AA123ZZ     | stackoverflow.com |
-----------------------------------
```

The content of this table_name `AA123ZZ` is for instance "*stackoverflow.com*"

Now what I want is a query where the result will be something like:

```
id: = 1
what is your favorite website: stackoverflow.com
```

So actually `AA123ZZ` stands for this question, I have no other way of matching these together, how can I do this?

I am sorry I cannot make this any clearer.
I got these two tables and indeed they seem to be missing something.

### So to try make this a bit clearer.

In the content table the table name `AA123ZZ` is 'code' for the question.

The maker of the database should just have placed the question as column name in stead of this code `AA123ZZ`. Now I need to match this code to what is inside `meta_data`.

So in meta_data in the question_column you can find: "favorite website"
and in the `column_code` you will find `AA123ZZ`.

in the content table in the `AA123ZZ` column you will find: *stackoverflow.com*

As you can see I cannot match these easily on a inner join.

So is there a way to match a column_name from one table to the contents of a column in another table?

Comment: Which column stand for the answer - i.e. stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: It seems your tables are missing something, I am assuming you will be using the content id field to fill your column_code and have on your content table a field that is called reply, then you could do something like this: `SELECT q.id, q.question, a.reply FROM meta_data q LEFT JOIN  content a ON q.column_code = a.id`

Comment: Yes, the question is unclear.

Comment: I understand this is a bit weird, unfortunately this is how I received it. I tried to make it a bit clearer in the question. Please have a new look at it to see if it helps.

Comment: Most likely you misunderstood your task. There is no point in having a field named `AA123ZZ`, it should be a field content, not name.

Comment: I totally agree that AA123ZZ should be field content and not a field name. Like I said this (crappy) database I got and need to work with that. So no misunderstanding, just a crappy database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't join tables where the `column name` itself is variable. You're going to need to fix the schema here, perhaps to include a `foreign key` value to the `meta_data` table from the `content` table and from there you can do a simple `join` on the two tables.

[Read more on foreign keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I will create a new table with all correct data. Matching arrays from both tables to each other.

Comment: @BonifatiusK if you can create a new table then why not just make it right and use the content id rather then the column name and rename the AZwhatever to something like reply or w/e